# Complex number / bary geometric problem in a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry, triangles, barycentric-coordinates

> Let $ABCD$ be a convex cyclic quadrilateral, such as triangles $BCD$ and $CDA$ are not equilateral. Prove that, if $A$-Simson line is perpendicular to Euler line in $BCD$, $B$-Simson line is perpendicular to Euler line in $ACD$.

I know the following definitions, but I am not so sure of converting them into complex / barycentric form:

- Simson line is defined for each point $P$ on the circumcircle of the triangle $ABC$. The projections of $P$ on triangle's sides are collinear on $P$-Simson line;
- Euler line is the line that contains $O, G, H, O_9$ for each triangle, with these points being in order circumcenter, centroid, orthocenter and the center of the Euler circle, containing the altitudes' feet, midpoints of triangle's edges and midpoints of segments between verices and $H$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is Problem E2553 of American Mathematical Monthly by Sarma  asked in 1975 ; see this reference (p. 113) https://www.mathematrucker.com/problems_1975-1979.pdf. If I understand well, one can find its solution in a 1977 issue.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for the link! I managed to find the problem in your reference, but I couldn't find the solution, since I don't have access to American Math. Monthly.

Comment: For future reference, the poser provided a solution in the "Elementary Problems" section of _AMM_, vol. 84, #1, p. 60 (1977).  [The original problem is on p.851 of vol. 82, #8.]  Thank you, JeanMarie, for the link also:  I was unaware that such a reference existed.